# Python: list(data) outputs list twice in terminal when reading a binary file. Is it a bug?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I was trying to create my own hex editor that list the statistics of a binary file generated from Veracrypt. (I am still learning.)

File: Statistics.py

```
import Statistics
data = open('VERASHORT', 'rb').read()
print(list(data))
```

Anyways, the code above will print the hex of the binary file in a list format twice. It is only a three line code, but I am wondering why won't it work. I have modified the code from the author, so it should work. (Learning Python)

Here is the output after Python3 is ran. (List appears twice.)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 102, 102, 62, 90, 121, 113, 111, 92, 85, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 52, 32, 38, 92, 85, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 102, 102, 62, 90, 121, 113, 111, 92, 85, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 52, 32, 38, 92, 85, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102]
```

Comment: we are going to need more code.

Comment: did you save it in file `Statistics.py` ? I don't have module `Statistics` but `statistics` with lower `s`.

Comment: Yes, I saved that source code in Statistics.py.

Comment: Also, the VERASHORT binary file can be recreated by copy and pasting this hex sequence into your hex editor.     00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f

66 66 3e 5a 79 71 6f 5c 55 66 66 66 66 66 66 66

66 34 20 26 5c 55 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66

Comment: @Uber1337haxx0rWang That's exactly the problem: the code is executed twice, once during the original loading and then again during import. Just remove the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "import Statistics" is the cause.

You just load Statistics.py twice, then you execute that code two times.

BTW, Python packages needs lowercase https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: Good job, you solved it, I solved it independently too!! Thanks for the previous comments for a hint!!

Answer (score 0):

Add: I have solved the issue.

1. I have edited Statistics.py into Stat.py, this means that the module won't import itself!!
2. An error occured, the Statistics import that is in my first line of code should be LOWERCASE!! Thus, I changed it.
3. list(data) does not require any imports!!

That is where I screw up, thanks for the help guys. (The hints did help me obtain a quick conclusion!!)